# Деструктуризация массива в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Изучаю деструктуризацию в JavaScript.
Можно вытащить четные элементы из массива так

```js
const [,n2,,n4,,n6,,n8] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
console.log(n2, n4, n6, n8);
```

А можно ли в деструктуризацию вставить как-нибудь формулу, чтобы четные элементы вытаскивались из любого входного массива?

Comment: Вопрос: на сколько такое, эм, особое действо необходимо? Может воспользоваться `.filter` или чем-то более стандартным?

Comment: Применение не знаю, просто интересно

Comment: А зачем вам вообще столько отдельных переменных, какое применение?

Comment: У меня задача была сложить все четные элементы, я просто хотел сделать это в одну строку

Answer (score 2):

У вас в вопросе выводятся нечетные элементы

В в этом сниппете - четные:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const result = [...array.filter( (e,i) => !(i%2) )];
console.log(...result);
```

---

В в этом сниппете - нечетные:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const result = [...array.filter( (e,i) => i%2 )];
console.log(...result);
```

Comment: А что значат ...

Comment: @ValeriyPetukhov  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: @ValeriyPetukhov https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring#operator-spread

Comment: А тут для 'result' специально так сделано, чтобы разобрать и собрать массив обратно?))

Comment: @СергейМишин да, по аналогии с тем, как в вопросе автор вывел в консоль элементы через запятую